# How Comparator.compare() works?

Tags: java, kotlin

Learning Kotlin, I'm trying to understand how Java's [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface works - mainly the `compare()` function so I can utilize it.

I've tried reading the docs for `compare()` but I'd like a much simpler explanation of how it works.

What exactly is `x` and `y` in `compare(x, y)` when iterating over a list? Does it target & compare each pair of numbers when iterating? e.g:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

would it compare 1 and 2 (x and y), then 2 and 3 (x and y), then 3 and 4 (x and y)?

I have a Kotlin function that provides a comparator to sort a list in a descending order:

```
import java.util.*

fun getList(): List<Int> {
    val arrayList = arrayListOf(1, 5, 2)
    Collections.sort(arrayList, object: Comparator<Int> {
        override fun compare(x: Int, y: Int){
            return x < y
        }
    } )
    return arrayList
```

I'm not sure why the above function isn't the right syntax to complete that.

Comment: ...the sample you have shown is rather the Java-way of doing it. You may want to have a look at [`sortWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-with.html) (combined with [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html)) or [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html). Or have a look at [Kotlin collection ordering](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-ordering.html)

Answer (score 6):

It boils down to this statement from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

That is all there is to this. When you write a Comparator, you **define** what order you want. The key thing is that your method returns -1, 0, or 1. Depending on how you **want** those two incoming arguments to be ordered. (and yes, it doesn't need to -1 or 1, just negative, zero, positive).

In other words: the key point is that `compare()` serves in that contract. It defines an **order** on two elements. That is all there is to this.

When sorting data, it will be called each time when the underlying sorting code needs to know the order of two elements. So the exact "order" in which these calls take place, and what arguments are passed depends on the actual sorting algorithm, and the data you intend to sort.

From that point of view, your question implies that you are some overthinking the whole topic. Simply understand: you use a comparator when you intend to define a "custom" order for your objects/values.

And there is no sense in defining your "own" comparator for int, Int, or Integer, as these classes already define their natural order, so there is already [Integer.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) for example. The only use-case to define your own comparator for such a class would be when you want to order them differently. But most likely, you would then still use existing comparator functionality, and use other built in ways, for example to *reverse* the "natural" order.

Comment: Note that while strictly speaking, returning any positive or negative value is fine, the convention is to return `1` and `-1` when feasible.

Comment: @biziclop Adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression the sorting was more flexible. Is it simply: positive = ascending, negative = descending?

Comment: @Zorgan Again: sorting is **solely** based on order. You **define** the order that should be used. *Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.* In ascending order, 5 is smaller than 10, so "negative". If you want descending, 5 should be ordered AFTER 10, so positive. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But you can't choose how to "order" the numbers - it's only `x` and `y` from an unknown list? @GhostCat

Comment: @Zorgan Sorting a list is based on applying the SAME order for any x, y, z in that list. If x < y < z, then the sorted list MUST be x, y, z. If you now say: I want to "sort" it to x, z, y ... then that is not a sorted list. Sorting means that for any two entries, x < y, that x shows up before y. If you want to have the list organized in different ways, then you are NOT sorting. Then you are prescribing an overall order. Sorting and comparing only needs to consider TWO elements.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat I had a skewed view of what "sorting" was - that makes sense. However I don't understand what happens after the first comparison. Say I'm making an ascending sort of `listOf(2, 5, 1, 9)` - 2.compareTo(5) will obviously return -1 so there is no swap. However what happens next? 5 and 1 will swap because 5 is greater than 1 - however 2 is greater than 1 but is stuck as the first element.

Comment: That is what I wrote in my answer: it depends on the sorting algorithm. And you got that right: elements might be compared multiple times until they "reach" their final destination. So: study how sorting works... https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting . Beyond that: I hope we come to a closure here soon, as having extended discussions isn't what this site is meant for. Your basic problem is that skewed view on sorting, and you can address that by learning how the different sorting algorithms work.

Answer (score 3):

A `Comparator<T>` is simply a way to compare any 2 elements of type T.

> What exactly is x and y in compare(x, y) when iterating over a list?

When iterating, the comparator is not called at all.

When passed to the `Collections.sort()` method, the comparator is used anytime the underlying sorting algorithm needs to compare 2 elements.

> I'm not sure why the above function isn't the right syntax to complete that.

Your current implementation does not satisfy the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)). `compare()` needs to return a negative integer, 0, or a positive integer depending on how to 2 elements relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The `compare` documentation is pretty clear:

> return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first
>   argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So you have to return an `Int` from your function rather than a boolean.

To provide working Kotlin code, I include an example:

```
val list = listOf(1, 5, 2)
list.sortedWith(Comparator { x, y ->
       x.compareTo(y)
})
```

Sorting itself can be performed with different algorithms but they will utilize `compareTo` internally. The `Collections` documentation gives an idea:

> The documentation for the polymorphic algorithms contained in this
>   class generally includes a brief description of the implementation.
>   Such descriptions should be regarded as implementation notes, rather
>   than parts of the specification. Implementors should feel free to
>   substitute other algorithms, so long as the specification itself is
>   adhered to. (For example, the algorithm used by sort does not have to
>   be a mergesort, but it does have to be stable.)

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator` is only interface for classes which can be compared. It's about comparing ANY two objects. Nothing more, nothing less. From docs:

> @param o1 the first object to be compared.
>
> @param o2 the second object to be compared.
>
> @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the
>              first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the
>              second.

Sorting is completely other thing. It uses comparator (it would be hard to sort anything without knowing how to compare two elements), so you can provide your own way to sort collection.

But how is it sorted? All we know about sorting via `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)` is that sorting is stable. See more about sorting: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/